# org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusLeaderNotFoundException: Could not find leader nimbus from seed hosts

Tags: apache-storm

I am getting the below message.

> Could not find leader nimbus from seed hosts [master]. Did you specify
>   a valid list of nimbus hosts for config nimbus.seeds?
>
> Delete storm under zookeeper.try to use hostname or ip in nimbus.seeds

```
storm.zookeeper.servers :
 - "master"
 - "salve1"
 - "salve2"
storm.zookeeper.port : 2181
nimbus.seeds : ["master"]
nimbus.thrift.port : 6690
storm.local.dir : "/root/storm"
supervisor.slots.ports :
  - 6700
  - 6701
  - 6702
  - 6703
```

Why this can happen?

Comment: and i close zhe firewall.i think it`s not the problem of port

Comment: Is "master" a resolvable hostname on your machine? The message is telling you that the process you are running can't connect to "master".

Comment: i can connect the "master" and when i submit a task  problems arise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure Zookeeper is running, and is accessible on the machine you're running the command from. You can check this with `curl`. On the machine you're starting your `storm` command from, try running `curl master:2181`. You should get an empty reply.

e.g.

```
$ curl localhost:2181
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Do the same for the two other hosts you run Zookeeper on.

Then make sure `curl master:6690` also returns an empty reply, since that is the Thrift port you've configured.

If you are getting connection refused on either command, you need to fix your network setup, so the machines can talk to each other.

Comment: curl master:2181 faild. thanks for you help me find the true error. so the problem is in the zookeeper?

Comment: Yes. Zookeeper needs to be reachable from the machine you're running your `storm` commands on.

Comment: i fixed '[ERROR] Read a frame size of 1195725856, which is bigger than the maximum allowable buffer size for ALL connections'. this error initiation. thank you.